# image overlay for php generated items

Tags: javascript, php, css

So I have a roll over effect for my mock store, the images and info for each boxes are taking from .sql file and auto generated sections. I want it too cover each section. I could hard code it, but that's a little too draconian.

```
   <div id="scoll" class="group">
                <div class="container"> 
                    <div class="center_items">


                 <?php
        //external pages area
        include_once('config\database.php');
        include_once('object/chair.php');
        $database = new Database();
        $conn = $database->getConnection();
        $chair = new Chair($conn);
        $stmt = $chair->readAll();
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            ?>

            <div class="product_box" >


            <img src="img/<?php echo $row['THUMB']; ?>" alt="chair_image"> </a>
            <h4><a href="movies-details.php?detailsid=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"> <?php echo $row['chair_name'];?></a> </h4>
            <p>$<?php echo $row['PRICE'];?></p>
            <div class="buy-box-shadow group">
            <a href="chair-details.php?detailsid=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" class="btn">Buy me!</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>


                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div>


JS

    onload=init;

    function init() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("product_box")[0].onmouseover = function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            mouseOver();
        }
    document.getElementsByClassName("product_box")[0].onmouseout  = function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            mouseOut();
        }

    function mouseOver() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("buy-box-shadow")[0].style.opacity = .9;
    }

    function mouseOut() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("buy-box-shadow")[0].style.opacity = 0;
    }
```

See the code is hard coded to be the first element, a tad confused on how to make it go for every element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for that, you can do it just with CSS.

```
.product_box .buy-box-shadow {
    opacity: 0.9;
    display: none;
}
.product_box:hover .buy-box-shadow {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do this with forEach.  Like so:

```
function init() {
var product_boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("product_box");
product_boxes.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array){
    currentValue.onmouseover = function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        mouseOver();
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm that's interesting I learned about foreach loops a little bit ago so for the shadow box how would i write that? I've tried mimicking the first example but it doesn't work. i write it as function mouseOver() {
     shadow_boxes.style.opacity = .9;
}

Comment: Hmm... I see.  Why are we breaking it out into multiple functions like this?  Or rather, why are you calling getElementByClassName in the functions you're calling from within mouseover and mouseout?  I would try passing the currentValue to the function and then just using the .style.opacity properties to set the opacity from there.  You already have the DOM object, you should be able to change its property using what was returned to the original array.  Maybe like this: `function mouseOver(e) { e.style.opacity = 9;}`  Just pass currentValue to the mouseOver function when it's called.